# Q:Flutter How to get value from parameter inside class

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm newbie for android and flutter development, I want to ask something about push notification, I build firebase_messaging by own self because its not support big notification image

The problem is I cant get the _url

```
  int _selectedTab = 1;
  static String _url = "";
  static const platform =
      const MethodChannel('com.example.loop_app_flutter_v2');

  @override
  Future<void> _firebaseMessageListener() async {
    String getRedirect;
    String url;
    try {
      final String result =
          await platform.invokeMethod('getFirebaseMessagePayload');
      getRedirect = '$result';
      Map<String, dynamic> notif = jsonDecode(getRedirect);
      url = notif["url"]; //payload success and url show up

    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      getRedirect = "Failed : '${e.message}'.";
    }
    this.loadNotificationData(getRedirect);
    setState(() {
      _url = url; // i want to assign url to _url and put in List Widget
      print(url); //print show up url
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _firebaseMessageListener();
}

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    new MainArtikel(),
    new Webpage(url: _url),
    new FeedBack(),
    new Setting()
  ];
```

Comment: Please post reproducible code !

Comment: I don't really see the point of using static here since you're calling it from the class only... Anyway can you explain what the error is, maybe with some logs and give us the entire widget declaration ??

Comment: i want to pass parameter from notification, if i tap notification, application launch and redirect to class webpage with url payload, but _url value is empty